# Should Rudraksha be taken off before going to washroom,having sexual intercourse,masturbating etc?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, rudraksha

I would like to know if Rudraksha should be taken off before going to washroom,having sex/masturbating or in any other impure state. 
The reason for my doubt is that in [this video](https://youtu.be/LqhOYGS4UAg), Puri Sri Sankaracharya Ji says that his Guru Swami Sri Karpatri Ji Maharaj always used to remove Rudraksha before going to washroom. From there Sankaracharya Ji realized that Rudraksha should not be worn during impure state.

Now my question is if "impure state" also includes having sexual intercourse or masturbating. Also, is there any Shastra pramana for the same as Sri Sankaracharya Ji only made His statement after observing His Guru a self-realized saint Swami Karpatri Ji Maharaj.